# find 2×2 matrix such that $ A^2 =-I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, examples-counterexamples

find 2×2 matrix such that  $ A^2 =-I$ . I think that eigenvalue of $A^2$ is 0 or positive but eigenvalue of $-I$ is negative so we haven't matrix wih this condition.

Comment: Think of rotation by $90°$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. So what is wrong?

Comment: "So what is wrong?" A real-valued matrix can have complex-valued eigenvalues.

Comment: You will find that the characterisic equation is quadratic and can have non-real roots even if coefficients are real. In particular if the characteristic equation were $\lambda^2+1=0$ you would have roots $\pm i$ with $i^2=-1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given condition implies $A^2+I=0$. So characteristic polynomial is $x^2+1$. So any matrix with trace 0 and determinant 1 will satisfies your condition!

In particular, take $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers

Comment: Indeed $A=\begin{pmatrix} 13&17\\-10&-13 \end{pmatrix}$ will do, to use an integer valued matrix which looks nothing like the other examples people are giving.

Comment: I agree! ......